# Column 'dataColumn' does not belong to table: Using Ado.Net Datatable and $.ajax()

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-5, ado.net, datarow, formcollection

I am using MVC5 with Ado.net datatable. I have a method in a Controller. I would like to use an ajax call to send form data to this method. i want to call this method in my create action when creating new records, so I can just pass the collection of datarows in the datatable to create multiple records simultaneously.

This is how my method looks

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    public void InsertRecord(FormCollection collection)
    {

        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0) // if no columns defined
        {
            //create columns
            dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Length", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Breadth ", typeof(double));
            dt.Columns.Add("Height ", typeof(double));.
            dt.Columns.Add("IsMeasured ", typeof(bool));
        }    
        if (collection != null)
        {
            DataRow row = dt.NewRow();

            row.SetField<string>("Name", collection["Name"]);
            row.SetField<double>("Length", Convert.ToDouble(collection["Length"]));
            row.SetField<double>("Breadth", Convert.ToDouble(collection["Breadth"]));
            row.SetField<double>("Height", Convert.ToDouble(collection["Height"]));
            row.SetField<bool>("IsMeasured", Convert.ToBoolean(collection["IsMeasured"]));
            dt.Rows.Add(row);
         }
 }
```

my ajax call looks like:

```
function AddItem() {
       var inputs = $('#DetailCard input, #DetailCard select').serialize();
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/CreateRecords/InsertRecord',
            data: inputs,
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function (info) {
                if (info.result == "Error") {
                    alert(info.message);
                }
            }
        });
        };
```

my submit button:

```
<input type="button" value="Add" onclick="AddItem()" />
```

When I run the project I can see the first two column fields of the data row (Name and Length) are filled (populated). However when the program gets to the "Breadth" column it crashes and gives an error (**System.ArgumentException ... 'Breadth' does not belong to table**).
I have double checked everything but cannot see what I am missing.

Comment: Definitely you cannot do `SetField<T>` if the column is not created or not exist yet. Please add more snippet to explain how `DataTable` instance containing 2 column fields was created.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto.. I have updated the information to show the entire method. I hope I have clarified.

Comment: Those extra spaces on the column names is the main problem, because the `DataColumn` name doesn't automatically trim spaces. Remove all of them and your code will working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Your code sample above has a space after the name (ie "Breadth ", not "Breadth") when you are creating the table; the name of the column must match exactly.

Extra space after these 3 for the name:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Breadth ", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("Height ", typeof(double));.
dt.Columns.Add("IsMeasured ", typeof(bool));
```

Change to:

```
dt.Columns.Add("Breadth", typeof(double));
dt.Columns.Add("Height", typeof(double));.
dt.Columns.Add("IsMeasured", typeof(bool));
```